# How to remove a specific color in an image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal, image-editing, monochrome

I am not an expert photoshop user but have been trying to use more of it in what I currently do.

I have a black and white image from
which I am trying to remove all the white.

I cannot use the magic wand/delete
because the white is in literally hundreds of places and in some cases very tiny.

Is there a method to strip the white off, leaving just the black?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There's A LOT of ways to do this but the best method will depend on the image. Post a screenshot of what you're working with and then we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 40):

Indeed you should perform right selection.

`Select->Color Range` and click on the spot colored with color  you want to select - you will see the change on the preview screen.

Also, you can choose the color from sampled colors drop down menu

Fuzziness should be set to 0.

If you press SHIFT while selecting (you can also click Shift and drag of the image) it will select all the spots with the same color....

After selection was made you can perform on it any action you want...

Comment: if you want to remove the  white background around your picture but without removing the white spot inside your picture:  set your layer to invisible (uncheck the eye), and remove the selection you want to keep by pressing alt (-)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way you can do this is by **unchecking the contiguous** (marked yellow in screenshot) location when selecting the white colour with **magic wand**. This will select only those areas which you want. To get exact colour or colour range you can set the Tolerance as per your image.

Here is an screenshot with my imaginary image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to eraser tool, long press, and click magic eraser tool. and then click on the region that you want to erase
[image: step2]

and below is the final touch i have made to my picture. I erase all the white region of the picture and then I just save as png.
[image: after]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Method]

Last item on coloumn to the right.

Also. Method 2 will involve blending and experimenting. if you are looking to increase the complexity of your images - this is a great starting points for viariants

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The quickest option I would use if you are only removing white background,  is on the layers panel, create a new layer under your image with the desired background colour / photo etc. then on the layer you are trying to remove the white from, select the option "multiply" from the dropdown next to the opacity %.

similarly "screen" will do the same thing for Black in the image.

Comment: Unfortunately you can use this method to take out a color to save as transparency.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want transparency where the white is, you don't need Photoshop. This is a very simple thing to do in PowerPoint...
1. Paste the image into PowerPoint
2. Select the image
3. Hit the Format tab
4. Click Color
5. Click Set Transparent Color
6. Click on one of the white areas you want to remove.
7. Right click the image and Save as Picture.

Of course, this will only remove one color, so if there are shades of grey in your white, this is NOT a solution.

Comment: Sorry, but Powerpoint is not a tool to prepare good images, it is a tool to create style sheets.  To create or change images one should only use programs prepared to do that, like gimp, photoshop, illustrator (vector graphics), Corel Draw etc.

Comment: Actually, Kurt, PowerPoint 2010 has some very powerful image manipulation tools, and it is less intimidating than Photoshop.  For many users, the changes you can make to images in PowerPoint may be good enough for what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg71UMkatcA) might help you!

Steps shown in video:

1. Create a new layer,
2. Create clipping mask over the layer on which color is to be removed
3. Switch blending mode of new layer to color (3rd last)
4. Paint with care (Resampling again and again for color tones)
5. Done!

Comment: Hi Hash Tang, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!